# How do I upgrade from 14.04 to 14.04.2?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I want to upgrade from 14.04 to 14.04.2 without doing a fresh install.

I want to keep all my configuration the same.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using 14.04.1 and when I used Software Updater it said that no updates were available. But when I did the terminal commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

it fetched and installed ~ 2 M of updates, and now I'm at 14.04.2

My Lubuntu 14.04.1 installation did exactly the same thing.

Comment: okay thanks...but is it going to affect all my present configuration if i do it?the way u suggested

Comment: No, it will just install the updates. Your configuration will remain untouched.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: You shoud run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` also. @Takkat is correct. Otherwise kernel modules won't get upgraded.

Comment: Doing sudo apt-get dist-upgrade did nothing for the particular update the OP was asking about.  In general though, yeah.

Answer (score 6):

Just install all the updates and you'll get it.

The "point releases" of Ubuntu LTS versions aren't something special, as standard releases are. The same repositories are used.

In other words, 14.04.2 = 14.04 + all current updates.

Comment: but i see the release notes..there are few more upgrades...but My question is..do all the updates for 14.04 will have the same as as 12.04.2?

Comment: Probably yes. I can't check it now because I'm running 14.10. But I remember, the previous release (14.04.1) came without any release notes or other visible signs...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the new 3.16 kernel coming with the hardware enablement stack, you should use these terminal commands:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

Source:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: That link is quite interesting. I always thought that point releases have new kernels. But from this page it seems that is not true. The point release and the new kernel are somewhat independent. And indeed after an apt-get dist-upgrade and reboot the welcome message says on a virtual machine that I am on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS ... Linux 3.13. That is the new point release, but the original kernel! A fresh installation of the same point version would result in the newer 3.16 kernel, if I understand well.

Comment: I think fresh install is a better idea..i just ran the above command im getting error on dependencies etc..

Comment: Im not able to do this; Getting errors on core applications of 14.04:

`The following packages have unmet dependencies: account-plugin-facebook : Depends: libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth but it is not going to be installed or ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts but it is not going to be installed
 account-plugin-google : Depends: libaccount-plugin-google but it is not going to be installed or ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts but it is .... etc.` Know why?

Comment: @HontváriLevente Yes.  The distinction is the Hardware Enablement  (HWE) stuff, which comes with new installs and which you can pick and choose from for new kernels, xorg etc.  The question is, what is best for which circumstances....