# Update Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 14.04.2 LTS without any command

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, update-manager

well i was wondering why on each update we have to goto run to terminal and run commands like

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-lts-raring
```

**OR**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**OR**

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

why it's so tricky always and why UBUNTU don't just give update to `Software Updater`.

i am using UBUNTU `12.04 LTS` this time and i suddenly ran out of thought that i should upgrade my OS. And then the very next moment i was thinking by upgrading to new version all of my files on Desktop or any other repose and all of the Environments and other development things will be gone ?? will i loss my data because i am such kind of person who's desktop is always so important :p i always put my working projects on my desktop, i know it's a bad habit but i do it.

by the way point is there any safer way to do it and not messing with my desktop or document and download files and environmental variables and other stuff, without going into `TERMINAL`

hope you guys will come out of some nicer solution for me because I've already checked out following links.

[How to do Ubuntu upgrade 14.04 to 14.04.2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587609/how-to-do-ubuntu-upgrade-14-04-to-14-04-2)

[How to Upgrade Ubuntu 12.04.2, 12.04.3 to 12.04.4, the next Hardware Enablement Stack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336527/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-12-04-2-12-04-3-to-12-04-4-the-next-hardware-enablement)

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Software Updater says `no updates for me`

[image: no updates for me]

Software Updates Options

[image]

Comment: You don't have to go to a terminal, the Update Manager GUI can take care of all this.

Comment: @muru by update manager you mean Software Updater with A icon yeah?

Comment: Yes (the icon may vary).

Comment: @muru well it just keep updating new thing daily but its not gonna update my Ubuntu version, it's always 14.04LTS..

Comment: It does ask you about HWE updates.

Comment: well i've just opened it and it says the software on your computer is up to date.. whenever my Ubuntu version is still 14.04

Comment: @muru checkout the edited question..!

Comment: Now we have got to your actual question. Could you edit out the irrelevant parts and ass the output of `lsb_release -sc` as well?

Comment: Automatic updates with gui should be controlled in Software-Settings -> Software & Updates -> Updates tab. Do you have that enabled ?

Comment: @Serg see my edited question dude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

14.04.2 is only a version for the image release. The version of Ubuntu itself is still 14.04. The appended numbers on LTS versions are simply later image milestone releases, to differentiate them from the original installer images. If you've installed all the updates, then you have the same packages as are on the 14.04.2 image already. If you need the HWE updates, you can install them, though they are not necessarily required, depending on your hardware.

Comment: So that's what the user wanted to know ? he wanted to see 14.04.2 in System Settings -> Details ? Makes sense now. By the way, add to the answer, that the user actually can see the full version image release number if they go to TTY 1 - 7 or do `lsb_release -d` or `cat /etc/issue`

Comment: thanks to @Serg :p i tried `lsb_relrase -d` and the output was `Description: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS`;)

Answer (score -3):

Try switching between

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

First, type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Let the updates take place and then reboot.

Then, type:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Let the updates take place then reboot.

Just remember the updates need to be installed sequentially. You just can't go from one LTS to the next higher LTS.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  You seem to have a slight misunderstanding of the function of `sudo apt-get update`.  It doesn't require a reboot, and it doesn't actually update your computer.