# Upgrade from 14.04 to 14.04.2 broke nvidia/x... how can I fix that?

Tags: nvidia, xorg

I followed the answer from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587609/how-to-do-ubuntu-upgrade-14-04-to-14-04-2), using

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

early on this week. Kernel 3.16 installed fine; all my kernel modules were built; restart; all fine. Then, yesterday came a kernel update; I installed it ... later on rebooted; and now X doesn't come up. I already purged my nvidia packages; and installed nvidia-349 from xorg edgers (again). I ran "sudo nvidia-xconfig" which tells me it created a new XF86Config in /etc/X11.

But after a reboot... still no graphical console. Probably the reason for this mess is the fact that I had some additional nouveau drivers installed from the xorg edgers PPA before.

I have seen similar problems in the past, but back then, it was "enough" to `apt-get purge` the nvidia packages and reinstall. I checked `aptitude search utopic`; and it "seems" that all important things (like kernel headers, `xserver-xorg-cort-lts-utopic`) ... are all there.

Any specific advice (which packages to check for, which things to purge/re-install) is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily, I could fix it myself.

First I purged the nvidia drivers again.

Then I did a

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm xserver-xorg-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-core-lts-utopic
```

Rebooted; and at least the nouveau driver is up and running again.